# IE browser issue working with java script

Tags: javascript, console

I was trying to open a subtab using javascript, in the js console in IE browser and I am getting this error:

> URl does not exists

But the URL is correct and its opening in Firefox browser the way I would expect.

Code:

```
 window.parent.sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function(result) {
                        console.debug('inside call back' + result.id);
                        alert(result.id);
                        window.parent.sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id, '/00T/e?retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}&tsk5=Call&title=Call&followup=1&what_id={!Account.Id}',true,'Log a Note', null);
                    });
```

I am using `window.parent` since I kept the code in iframe, for iframe to identify its primary tab id.

Comment: Is it possible that the iframe is in a different domain to window.parent?